# Translate word from file by the key from second file (C language)

Tags: arrays, c, file, encryption, key

I have 2 files in first i got digit-encrypted word(like 34 43 54 45), in another file I got key(34f, 23r...). So I already defined key as 2 dynamic arrays of numbers and letters. And already got in array word which need to be decrypted. But i dont know how to decrypted it...

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   // Here is 2 files
   FILE *fKey;
   FILE *fCipher;
   // defenition of arrays for dynamic allocation
   int *keys;
   char *values;
   int *text;

   fKey = fopen("key.txt", "r");
   fCiper = fopen("ciper.txt", "r");

   if ((fKey == NULL) || (fCiper== NULL))
            {
              printf("Error! Could not open the file.\n");
              exit(-1);
            }
   printf("File was loaded successfully.\n");
   // definition of variables
   int num = 0, count = 0, count_text = 0, symbol = 0, sifra = 0;
   char c;

   while(fscanf(fKey, "%d%c", &num, &c)>0){
   printf("Row %d%c\n", num, c);
   count++;
   }
   printf("Key got %d values.\n", count);

   values = (char*)malloc(count* sizeof(char));
   if(values == NULL){
    printf("Not enought memory.\n");
    return 1;
   }

   keys = (int*)malloc(count* sizeof(int));
   if(keys == NULL){
    printf("Not enought memory.\n");
    return 1;
   }

   rewind(fKey);
   int i = 0;
   while(fscanf(fKey, "%d%c", keys + i, values + i)>0){
   printf("Row from memory %d%c\n", *(keys + i), *(values + i));
   i++;
   }


   while(fscanf(fChiper, "%d", &symbol)>0){
   count_text++;
   }
   text = (int*)malloc(count_text* sizeof(int));


   /*Then i tried to tranlate but idk*/


   free(text);
   free(values);
   free(keys);
   fclose(fKey);
   fclose(fChiper);

   return 0;
}```
````

Comment: So for exemple, if your fKey file contains `34h 35e 36l 37o` and your fCipher file contains `34 35 36 36 37`, what do you want to do? You want to print `hello` on stdout? You want to store `hello`in a file?

Comment: you need to define how you want to decrypt,based on that we can apply key on the value, but you have not specified any.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understood what you're trying to achieve, this should do the job:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char get_value_from_key(int symbol, int *keys, char *values, int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < n)
    {
        if (symbol == keys[i])
            return (values[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return ('\0');
}

int main()
{
    FILE *key_file, *cipher_file;

    int *keys, num = 0, count = 0, count_text = 0, symbol = 0, sifra = 0, i;
    char *values, *text, c;

    key_file = fopen("key.txt", "r");
    cipher_file = fopen("cipher.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(key_file, "%d%c", &num, &c) > 0)
        count++;
    rewind(key_file);

    keys = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * count);
    values = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * count);

    i = 0;
    while(fscanf(key_file, "%d%c", keys + i, values + i) > 0)
        i++;

    while(fscanf(cipher_file, "%d", &symbol) > 0)
        count_text++;
    rewind(cipher_file);

    text = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (count_text + 1));
    text[count_text] = '\0';

    i = 0;
    while(fscanf(cipher_file, "%d", &symbol) > 0)
        text[i++] = get_value_from_key(symbol, keys, values, count);

    printf("%s\n", text);

   free(text);
   free(values);
   free(keys);
   fclose(key_file);
   fclose(cipher_file);

   return (0);
}
```

Note that I removed malloc protections for better readability.

**Exemple:**

key.txt: `34h 35e 36l 37o`

cipher.txt: `34 35 36 36 37`

output: `hello`